# Display number of markers on a map on the webpage

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a line of text to my webpage below an embedded map which says how many pins are currently on the map ... "This map currently has XX number of pins."
I would like to get the XX to automatically fill in with the current number. This is how the marker information is stored..

```
  var locations = [
    ['  place a ',  21.81821, 63.84583, 0.000000  ],
    ['  place b ',  34.56343, 67.89073, 0.000000  ]];
```

and markers created and clustered here

```
var markers = [];

  var marker, i;

     for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
     map: map
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
     return function() {
     infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }})(marker, i));
       markers.push(marker)}

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{gridSize:40});}
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I was thinking maybe document.write would work to automatically call the length of an element (locations/marker/markers...)  as follows

```
.
.
var XX = locations.length

<div id="map"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.write("the map currently has", [XX], "pins");
</script>
```

But I am having trouble implementing it, using the example locations the read out would say "the map currently has **2** pins"

Comment: I assume you have var XX = locations.length wrapped in <script> tags and also that it has a semi-colon after it?

Comment: yes to both of those. (accidentally chopped off the ; in pasting this) when I write document.write("the map currently has", [XX], "pins");
it just says "the map currently haspins"

Answer (score 0):

[MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) has a `getTotalMarkers()` function that returns the total number of markers in your cluster - no need to reinvent the wheel...

If I understand you correctly this *should* work (untested, will check as soon as I can):

```
//assumes an element with an id of marker-counter that you want to output to
document.getElementById("marker-counter").innerHTML = "the map currently has" + markerCluster.getTotalMarkers() + "pins";
```

*Update: link updated to point to MarkerClusterer docs instead of MarkerManager*

Comment: Thanks, so how do I get that to display in the text relating to my code above?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
document.write("the map currently has " + XX + " pins");
```

I see no reason for that not to work.